# IE11 on Windows 8.1 touch fires click events even when pointerup is not at the same location as pointerdown

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, touch, windows-8.1

I can not find a way to stop IE from firing click on links on a Windows 8.1 touchscreen when I move my finger on link. The link has "touch-action: none" as I don't want panning/swiping link cause a page scroll. If I set "touch-action" to auto IE stops firing click, but I can't do that due to project requirements. Any idea why is this happening and how it can be fixed? Could it be that there is a bug in IE implementation of pointer events? Test page is here:

http://repos.saeidmohadjer.com/bxslider-4/test/test.html

CSS

```
a.test {
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').on('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //trying to cancel all pointer events to avoid click firing in IE during swipe, but it's not working!
    $('.test').on('pointerdown pointerup pointermove pointercancel pointerover pointerout pointerenter pointerleave', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.type);
    });

    $('.test').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.type);
        alert('Link clicked!');
    });
});
```